# How can I run a spark program : i am confused between 2 choices

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a simple python file to count word using Pyspark (wordcount.py):

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext()
lines = sc.textFile(sys.argv[1])
word_counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(' ')) \
                   .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
                   .reduceByKey(lambda count1, count2: count1 + count2) \
                   .collect()

for (word, count) in word_counts:
    print(word, count)
```

I installed PySpark downloading the file in [https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html](https://stackoverflow.com)

As such in my workdir, I have:

- a spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3 folder
- a text file in my workdir : text.txt
- wordcount.py

if I want to run the py file; i have to type this:
`./spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3/bin/spark-submit ./wordcount.py ./text.txt`

If I try`python wordcount text.txt`  like any regular python file, it doesn't work whereas I did install spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3. Indeed, it tells me I didn't import PySpark. I don't get it because i installed Pyspark and when I run with spark-submit, everything is ok. So why cant' i run with `python wordcount text.txt`?

I know people run .py file with a jupyternotebook, so it is similar to doing `python wordcount text.txt`, isn't it?
Then why can't I do `python wordcount text.txt`?
is there a difference between `python wordcount text.txt` and `./spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3/bin/spark-submit ./wordcount.py ./text.txt`?

Comment: *it doesn't work* isn't very helpful.  What, exactly, does it do?  `spark-submit` submits the job to a Spark cluster server, as opposed to running it standalone.

Comment: It's possible that the package you downloaded included its own installation of Python.  You should try `sudo -H python -m pip install pyspark` to install it in your normal Python.